# ffmpeg write while converting video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to watermarking the video but after size of output video become larger than 800MB the ffmpeg stopped working without error. So what I think is that the buffer size is full. So my question is how to make ffmpeg release the finished part each 10 minutes instead of waiting after the full video being converted and then write it to the disk.

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mkv -i logo.png -report -filter_complex "overlay = 20:15,subtitles = 'sub.srt'" -codec:a copy output.mkv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can try is to output using the segment muxer and then stitch the various segments.

**Step 1**:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=20:15,subtitles='sub.srt'"
       -c:a copy -f segment -segment_time 600 out%d.ts
```

**Step 2**:

If you have three segments, it would look like this

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:out1.ts|out2.ts|out3.ts" -c copy output.mkv
```

Comment: But is there any way that can release the buffer after certain size limit?